# All my barrels are named index...and its confusing

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

Im working in VSCode in a large project with lots of barrels. It's bothersome and unnecessarily confusing that all my barrels are called index. The file path helps to differentiate but I would like to be able to more easily differentiate between barrels. Is this possible?

Idk if this is where I would ask this question, but i searched all over the internet and couldn't find anything.

[image: Screenshot of my barrels]

Comment: `barrels` ?????

Comment: the index file in a folder that exports that folders content